# Axios doesn't returning data as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm learning ReactJS. I'm trying to fetch data from weather API but when I console log in the component I'm getting this:

```
Promise{<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
{[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object}
```

but when I console log inside the `.then` then I am get all data successfully.
I'm attaching my code.

```
const App = () => {
const weatherData =  (capital) =>  axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${capital}`)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.current) // getting expected data
    return (response.data.current)
  })

<IndividualCountry weatherData={weatherData(countriesShow[0].capital)} />
}

const IndividualCountry = ({weatherData}) => {
  console.log('here', weatherData)  // Getting weird logs
  return()
}
```

I've omitted other things. So, why is this happening? Is it because promise is returning before the data is fetched? If this is so then how to correctly return values?

If I use some state here then after updating the state it will re render which is causing loop. So, I think updating state might not be a option here.

Comment: Thats not a right way to do the stuff ,save the returned data in state and pass that as props

Comment: If I'm saving it in state then it's re-rendered causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Promise is return `pending` state initially. It's having success callback as then and error callback as catch.

```
const App = () => {

const weatherData =  async (capital) =>  await axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${capital}`)
  

<IndividualCountry weatherData={weatherData(countriesShow[0].capital)} />
}

const IndividualCountry = ({weatherData}) => {
  console.log('here', weatherData)  // you will get data here
  return()
}
```

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) says,

A Promise is in one of these states:

```
pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
fulfilled: meaning that the operation was completed successfully.
rejected: meaning that the operation failed.
```

[image]

Comment: `data` is not defined in IndividualCountry

Comment: `TypeError: data is not a function` It says this

Comment: `data(countriesShow[0].capital)` please update your code here

Comment: Yes Yes I did that only. After doing that weatherData function became light color and then the abovemention TypeError

Comment: what is this `countriesShow[0].capital`?

Comment: Argument to the function weatherData

Comment: I have updated the code. Removed the state and used `async/await`

Comment: It says now `Promise(<pending>)` but inside that it has `[[PromiseResult]]: Object` and upon expanding that I can see data. How to get the data then?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `async` await like this:

```
const App = () => {
const weatherData =  async (capital) =>  {
    axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${capital}`)
console.log(data) 
} 

.......
```

Or try to debug using the `useEffect()`  hook

```
useEffect(async () =>{
const { data } =await axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${capital}`)

console.log(data)
}, [capital] )
```

**Also make sure that your environmental variables are loaded**  by trying to

```js
console.log(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${capital}`)
```

Grab the url from the console and then paste it on your browser to see if you are getting results.

Then try to call that function and see if you are still getting the same results

Comment: Yes! It has same results.

Comment: Have you ever try to call the api endpoint in a `useEffect()` hook?